# Determine the validity of the argument.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this question and was hoping I could get some help on it:

p∧q∧r → s

u →s

p∧u∧~r

∴q

I have found:
p is true
u is true
~r is true 
r is false.

But I am unsure what to do to find the validity of the statement. 
My thinking is that premise 1 is (~p ∨ ~q ∨ ~r) ∨ s where S is true but I get stuck here.

Hopefully this made sense and thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You cannot prove it; check it with truth table.

Comment: It's possible that $s$ just happens to be true even if none of $q$ is.  There are conditions that make $s$ true but *no* conditions that make that make it false.  You have know way of knowing if $q$ is true or not.

Answer (score 1):

No, $q$ does not follow. You can try it with $q$ both ways and see.

As you said, the third premise means $p$ is True, $u$ is True, and $r$ is False. Then the second premise means $s$ is True.

If $q$ is True, the first premise says $T \wedge T \wedge F \to T$, which is fine.

If $q$ is False, the first premise says $T \wedge F \wedge F \to T$, which is fine.

So we can conclude nothing about $q$.